# Django Model 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django

I am facing this error in Django

```
'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

This is my model:

```
class ProcessedPicture(models.Model):
    processed_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='processed_pictures')
```

Then I work the picture and assigned it like that:

```
def do_something():
   ...............
   rgb = Image.fromarray(image)
   return rgb
```

Then I am simply trying to save the the result to the S3 Storage. No forms, no request, nothing:

```
score = do_something()
processed = ProcessedPicture()
processed.processed_picture = score
processed.save()
```

And it fails with the above error. Any ideas folks?

Comment: I think the problem here, is you are passing a img object and trying to store in DB, in fact the DB only store the name od the img not the img itself, try to pass the file insted of the obj

Comment: You can not assign `score` to an `ImageField`, or at least not directly. You need to wrap it in a `FieldFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I am simply trying to save the the result to the S3 Storage.

This is not how the interface of a `FileField`/`ImageField` works. You can not just assign an `Image` to the field. Indeed, when you save an image, you do not only have the "image data", but also for example a filename. You can store it in a memory stream that you then wrap in a `NamedTemporaryFile`:

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as img_tmp:
    score = do_something()
    
    score.save(img_tmp, format='JPEG')
    img_tmp.flush()
    
    processed = ProcessedPicture()
    processed.processed_picture.save('name_of_the_file.jpg', File(img_tmp))
    processed.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Got it and it worked. Cheers